# Flow 3 item in a row, and when wrapped, last row items left aligned

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using the Layout discussed in this thread I am trying to create a blog HTML. [Live is here.](http://next.ankishpost.com/01/)

[the CSS of this portion is written like this →](https://www.screencast.com/t/WaDooG5OS4l)

```
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: calc(33% - 10px);
    margin-right: 10px;
    align-items: center;
```

But I think that there are better way to do this by using so many properties available in flex.

what is missing →

1. Currently, I am using this property margin-right: 10px; I think we can effectively use some property like space-between or space-around to give the gap between the items. I tried, but that didn't worked.
2. secondly, I want 3 Items in a row. there should be some property in the flex to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do like this

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;                   /* wrap items when not fit on a line */
  justify-content: space-between;    /* a gutter between if item is less than 33% wide */
}
.flexcontainer::before,
.flexcontainer::after {              /* fill out last row when odd amount of items */
  content: '';
  flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);  /* make them 33% - 10px wide  */
  order: 1;                          /* move them last */
}
.flexcontainer > div {
  flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);  /* make them 33% - 10px wide  */
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;            /* make border/padding be included in its set width */
}
.flexcontainer > div > div {
  padding: 10px;
}
.flexcontainer > div:nth-child(n+4) {
  margin-top: 10px;                  /* element not on first line moves down a little */
}
.flexcontainer > div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" alt="">
    <div>Some text</div>    
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" alt="">
    <div>Some text</div>    
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" alt="">
    <div>Some text</div>    
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" alt="">
    <div>Some text</div>    
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" alt="">
    <div>Some text</div>    
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" alt="">
    <div>Some text</div>    
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" alt="">
    <div>Some text</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir, I implemented this on my code. How to get rid of this [margin](https://www.screencast.com/t/XG63wQLH)

Comment: @AdiYogi Remove `padding: 10px` from `.flexcontainer > div` rule

Comment: In that case the text will also stick to the wall.

Comment: Also,
https://www.screencast.com/t/0bxMcXiuA → how to handle this situation when items are odd in number?

Comment: @AdiYogi Added a new rule to my answer that solve the padding issue `.flexcontainer > div > div`

Comment: @AdiYogi Added yet another rule, `.flexcontainer::before, .flexcontainer::after` that will take care of the issue with odd number of items ... and can I have my answer accepted/upvoted now :)

Comment: which rule site this one → `.flexcontainer > div > div {
  padding: 10px;`
}`

Comment: @AdiYogi It target the div with the text

Comment: Yes, sir. I have accepted. Can you change the title so that it could help in the better search for the future seeker?

Comment: sir, these properties didn't worked on my code → 
`.flexcontainer::before,
.flexcontainer::after {              /* fill out last row when odd amount of items */
  content: '';
  flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);  /* make them 33% - 10px wide  */
  order: 1;                          /* move them last */
}` Live Link [here](http://next.ankishpost.com/01/)

Comment: @AdiYogi Made an edit for your title, hope it is what you wanted to ask

Comment: Try `.sidebar-flex::before,
.sidebar-flex::after { content: ''; display: list-item; flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px); order: 1; }`

Comment: You are Nice and very precise. Always Helpful. If you think that this post could be beneficial to someone then please upvote me too.

Comment: @AdiYogi Thanks, and I was just about to do so...as it has such a good title ;)